# Flutter: custom fonts

Tags: flutter

**SOLUTION FOUND:**

**Using Android Studio solved the issue !!
I ran the app using Android Studio and everything worked fine!
It looks like VSCode did not cope well with Custom Fonts.
Therefore I would advise using Android Studio when somebody needs to add custom fonts**

I am trying to use a Google Fonts, called "Great Vibes" in my application.

This is what I did:

- I created a "fonts" directory in the root folder
- I copied the "GreatVibes-Regular.ttf" file in that directory (downloaded from the Google Fonts website)
- I made a reference to it in the pubspec.yaml (see below)
- When I want to use it, I referred to it in a TextStyle

Results:  The font is not used.

```
fonts:
    - family: GreatVibes
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/GreatVibes-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400


new Text('My New Font',
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontFamily: 'GreatVibes',
              fontSize: 16.0,
            )),
```

No error is reported.  I also validated the yaml via the [Online YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/)
Here is the output:

```
{
  "description": "My app", 
  "dependencies": {
    "http": "^0.11.3+16", 
    "shared_preferences": "^0.4.0", 
    "url_launcher": "^2.0.0", 
    "cupertino_icons": "^0.1.0", 
    "image_picker": "^0.4.1", 
    "flutter_facebook_login": "^1.0.3", 
    "flutter_localizations": {
      "sdk": "flutter"
    }, 
    "carousel_slider": "^0.0.4", 
    "connectivity": "^0.3.0", 
    "device_info": "^0.1.2", 
    "intl": "^0.15.5", 
    "font_awesome_flutter": "^7.0.0", 
    "scoped_model": "^0.2.0", 
    "flutter": {
      "sdk": "flutter"
    }, 
    "flutter_webview_plugin": "^0.1.4"
  }, 
  "flutter": {
    "fonts": [
      {
        "fonts": [
          {
            "asset": "fonts/GreatVibes-Regular.ttf", 
            "weight": 400
          }
        ], 
        "family": "GreatVibes"
      }
    ], 
    "assets": [
      "images/avatar.png", 
      "images/logo.png"
    ]
  }, 
  "name": "my_app", 
  "dev_dependencies": {
    "flutter_test": {
      "sdk": "flutter"
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried by removing the app from the device and reinstall it but nothing changes.

Would you have any idea?

Thanks

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.4.4 at d:\flutter
    • Framework revision f9bb4289e9 (5 weeks ago), 2018-05-11 21:44:54 -0700
    • Engine revision 06afdfe54e
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\boeledi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 25.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.24.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Dart Code extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code

[√] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Vscode shouldn't change anything. Maybe you just need a `flutter clean` or restarting your app/emulator.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

## How to use a custom font in a Flutter app

The OP has indicated that they solved their problem. This is a general answer for future readers.

### 1. Add a font to your project

- Right click on your project folder and go to **New > Directory**. Call it `assets`. It should be in your projects root directory.
- Copy and paste your font into the new `assets` directory. I'm just using a single font in my example, the regular [dancing script](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Dancing+Script?selection.family=Dancing%20Script) font. I renamed it to `dancing_script.ttf`.

### 2. Register the font

- Open your *pubspec.yaml* file.
- Add the fonts info under the `flutter` section. Indentation is mandatory.

  ```
  flutter:
    fonts:
    - family: DancingScript
      fonts:
      - asset: assets/dancing_script.ttf
  ```

### 3. Use the font in your theme or widget

- Now you can use your font by setting the `fontFamily` attribute in the `TextStyle` widget to whatever you called it in pubspec.yaml. For this example, I called it `DancingScript`.

  ```
  Text(
    'Hello world',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'DancingScript',
    ),
  )
  ```

### 4. Restart your app

- Whenever I add assets I find I need to do a full stop and restart. Otherwise I get errors.

## Notes

- Read the [documentation](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/fonts) for more help.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because the pubspec.yaml does not get saved automatically, so before running get packages, close the pubspec.yaml file and save it manually, run get packages again, it should now solve the problem.

This solution works both for Android Studio as well as VSCode.

Comment: I also had to make some changes to source file to force AS to recompile the app

Answer (score 1):

The google_fonts package for Flutter allows you to easily use any of the 960 fonts (and their variants) from fonts.google.com in your Flutter app.

First, add the google_fonts package to your pubspec dependencies.

To import GoogleFonts:

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
```

To use GoogleFonts with the default TextStyle:

```
Text(
  'This is Google Fonts',
  style: GoogleFonts.girassol(fontSize: 30),
),
```

Easy-Peasy :)

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest is to use `google_fonts`

Run this command:

With Flutter:

```
$ flutter pub add google_fonts
```

This will add a line like this to your package's pubspec.yaml (and run an implicit flutter pub get):

```
dependencies:
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
```

Import it
Now in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
...
Text(
   'You have pushed the button this many times:',
   style: GoogleFonts.oswald(textStyle: headline4
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `fonts` folder in base dir. Then download whatever font youlike in `fonts` folder. Then specify fonts like this in `pubspec.yaml` file.

[image: Font specification in pubspec.yaml file]

Answer (score 0):

"fonts" indentation is wrong use:

```
  fonts:
    - family: GreatVibes
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/GreatVibes-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
```

instead of:

```
fonts:
    - family: GreatVibes
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/GreatVibes-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
```

Otherwise this lines will be simply ignored and no error will be throw.

Answer (score 0):

Google fonts can be used without adding them into your flutter project in VS CODE.
Its a simple process to follow,

1. Open pub.dev and search for "google fonts"
2. You will find package something like "google_fonts"
3. Add dependencies: `google_fonts: ^3.0.1` to pubspec.yaml
   and run "flutter pub get" in Terminal window.
4. Import it in your Dart code, you can use:
   import `'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';`
5. Use it
   `Text('Hello World', style: GoogleFonts.greatVibes( fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))),`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Google Fonts` two ways , when `online` and `offline`

[image]

### Online

1. Download package [`google_fonts`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts), it fetches `google fonts` from the internet.
2. add import statement `import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart'`
3. Use it in the style

   ```
   Text(
     'I am having a great Vibe'
     style: GoogleFonts.greatVibes(),
   ),
   ```

### Offline

1. Visit the https://fonts.google.com/ and download the `greatVibes` font.
2. At the root directory, create a directory called `google_fonts`.
3. Copy-Paste `greatVibes.ttf` file into the `google_fonts` folder.
4. Open the `pubspec.yaml` file, Under the assets: section add the `-google_fonts/`

   ```
   Text(
     'I am having a great Vibe',
      style: GoogleFonts.getFont('greatVibes'),
      // style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'greatVibes') <-- This can also be used.
   ),
   ```

#### Note: Changing Google Font at App Level

If you want the font to change throughtout the app use the following code:

```
MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.greatVibes(
      Theme.of(context).textTheme,
    ),
   // fontFamily:'greatVibes' <-- this can also be used
  ),
  home: GoogleFontDemo(),
);
```

For futher reference refer [this](https://www.flutterbeads.com/google-fonts-in-flutter/) article.